# How can setup.py generate a file in /usr/bin and what does load_entry_point in pkg_resources do?

Tags: python, setuptools

How do packages such as [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) manage to execute via command line after being installed? What is required to achieve this? I looked at the source code and I do not understand.

The installer somehow generated a script in `/urs/bin/autopep8`
From my understanding the `/usr/bin` folder contains [executable files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045) which are loaded after the user signs in. However, the code located in `/urs/bin/autopep8` was not in the source code. Did `setuptools` create this code? Which method in `setup.py` generated it?

Comment: 1. Using `load_entry_point`. 2. It puts scripts in `/usr/bin`. What exactly do you want to know? `autopep8:main` in `setup.py` means the script should execute [this function](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/blob/master/autopep8.py#L3609) when called. Do you actually want to know how the mechanics work, or are you just having problems implementing this in your own package (in which case give a [mcve])?

Comment: I have removed the second question as you should ask one at a time. But it's reasonably straightforward: `function()()` means that `function()` returns a new function, then you call that new function too. It's like; `new_func = function(); new_func()`, it's not special syntax or anything. Functions are first-class objects in Python, so they can be parameters and return values.

Comment: Thanks for editing the post and the detailed, linked answers. I would like to understand how to implement this behaviour in my own package.

Comment: That's pretty simple, you just need: 1. a function to act as your entrypoint (`main` in `autopep8`); and 2. to tell `setuptools` what the command should be named and where to find the entrypoint (as `autopep8` does [here](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/blob/master/setup.py#L61); the key is the command name and the value is the path to the function to call). Then `python setup.py install` should create the appropriate script in the correct place. Have you tried this? What went wrong? See https://packaging.python.org/distributing/?highlight=entry_points#scripts for more guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was reading through this https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html and was finding it overwhelming! It's why I was reading the source code. The link you sent me is awesome as it contains a sample project. I have one final question, the entry point in the sample project setup.py file https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py#L111 is to a folder which contains an `__init__.py` file. Does this mean that the pointer can be to a file in the same directory or a folder with an init file?

Comment: Yes, it can be in any module (i.e. either a `.py` file or a directory with an `__init__.py` in it) within the package.